# CABasicAnimation not following duration

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

I am trying to create a basic animation that makes an image pulse from colored to grey however when I set it up it blinks way too fast even though my `.duration` attribute of the animation is set to 5 seconds Here is my code:

```
public func beginBlinking(){

    blinking = true
    let pulseAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    pulseAnimation.duration = 5
    pulseAnimation.fromValue = 0
    pulseAnimation.toValue = 1
    pulseAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    pulseAnimation.autoreverses = true
    pulseAnimation.repeatCount = FLT_MAX

    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
        self.layer.add(pulseAnimation, forKey: "animateOpacity")
    }

}
```

Thanks for any assistance.

**Edit:** Just to add, the **code does work** but the problem is that the **animation does not follow the duration set by the `duration` attribute.** It animates extremely fast. I am also programming in the swift playgrounds app for iPad and it does work in the xcode simulator so it may be a bug there.

Comment: Have you tried taking your `self.layer.add` out of the `DispatchQueue` block'?

Comment: @Magnas yeah then it doesn't start flickering until a few seconds after it's supposed to be called but it then does flicker normally when it starts (when it is out of that block).

Comment: The duration is in milliseconds. Therefore, if you want it to run for 5 seconds then you need to set the duration to 5000.0.